# dispatcher does not trigger correctly: Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher

this one might be a bit difficult to explain but I ll do my best.

Environment is a WPF MVVM app.

One of the class includes:
...

```
public ObservableCollection<Rat> Rats { get; set; }
```

...

```
 public void UpdateRats(int nbRats)
        {
            try
            {
                if (nbRats > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nbRats; i++)
                    {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Rats.Add(new Rat()));
                        // Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(  new Action(()  => Rats.Add(new Rat()   )));
                        //   Rats.Add(new Rat());
                    }
                }
                if (threadSimul != null && !threadSimul.IsAlive)
                {
                    threadSimul = new Thread(new ThreadStart(simul));
                    threadSimul.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

When UpdateRats is invoked by the thread that created this object, everything works fine.
When it is invoked from a different thread, execution seems to stop at dispatcher invocation:
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Rats.Add(new Rat()));

Debugger stops showing any activity in this thread although step by step debug does not show evidence that it exits the thread.
The thread where is still alive, but I don't see anything happen in it.

Could I be calling the dispatcher incorrectly?

Is there any reason why?

If relevant, the second thread is created this way:

```
 threadSimul = new Thread(() => simul());
            threadSimul.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            threadSimul.Start();
```

and Simul contains:

```
...
    UpdateRats(n);
...
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this kind of issue before. Usually by creating the dispatcher outside of your method, it works. Try to create it in your constructor. Something like:

```
private Dispatcher _dispatcher;

public class RatManager()
{
    _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
}
```

BTW, I wouldn't call the Dispatcher.Invoke method each time you make the loop. This would look better (at least for me)

```
// Assuming you already created a Dispatcher variable
_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
  // Loop here
}
```

Note that I'm using BeginInvoke here. Unless you specifically need the operation to be executed Synchronously, BeginInvoke is always better because it doesn't block the UI thread

Comment: Same result with your proposal. Thx anyway.